# Замена элементов массива по содержанию

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Допустим, есть массив:

```
String[] a = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "-", "5", "6", "-", "8", "9"};
```

Можно ли в нём заменить все `-` на `0`?

Comment: `String[] a = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "-", "5", "6", "-", "8", "9"};  
  int length = a.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
   if (a[i].equals("-"))
    a[i] = "0";
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
   System.out.println(a[i]);
  }`

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Java-8:

```
Arrays.asList(a).replaceAll(s -> s.equals("-") ? "0" : s);
```